# Putting a symbol over another one

Tags: symbols, accents

I am currently working on a mechanical project. As such, I use the notation of x, x° and ¨x, but can't find a way to put circles (o letter) over my symbols like varphi, theta...
I know there are other notations, but this one is easier to read, especially with long equations.

Comment: How about `\overset`: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Above_and_below

Comment: In general: the `\smash{something}` command allows its argument to overlap wherever you put it. Then, you can move it using `\raisebox` and `\hspace` commands. This may not be the best way to do what you want, but it has the advantage of being universal, at least in text mode.

Comment: In certain cases, the `stackengine` package can provide effective stacking tools.

Answer (score 2):

For two dots and circles over letters in math mode, you can use `\mathring` or `\ddot` as follows, also with Greek letters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\mathring{x}$
$\ddot{x}$
$\mathring{\theta}$
$\ddot{\theta}$
$\mathring{\varphi}$
$\ddot{\varphi}$

\end{document}
```

[image]